# Combining show/hide toggle with radio buttons AND checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, radiobuttonlist

I can toggle the show/hide of a checkbox because it can be unchecked but the behavior is different on a radio group because clicking a checked radio button doesn’t uncheck it, only clicking another radio button in the same group.

[DEMO WORKS FOR CHECKBOX NOT RADIO GROUPS](http://jsfiddle.net/DivineChef/378u301s/)

How can I modify this so it works for radio buttons and checkboxes in the same function? In this example I can click Item4 but it doesn’t hide upon clicking the others in the radio group.

How it should work: 
Put data-info-id="infox" on the input
Put id="infox" on the container usually a div

jQuery solutions are welcome.

HTML

```
    <input type="checkbox" id="item1" data-info-id="info1" />
    <label for="item1">Item 1 Checkbox</label>
    <br/>
    <div id="info1">Content checkbox group</div>
    </p>
    <input type="radio" id="jb1" name="jb" />
    <label for="jb1">Item2 Radio</label>
    <br/>
    <input type="radio" id="jb2" name="jb" />
    <label for="jb2">Item3 Radio</label>
    <br/>
    <input type="radio" id="jb3" name="jb" data-info-id="info2" />
    <label for="jb3">Item4 Radio</label>
    <br/>
    <div id="info2">Content radio group</div>
```

CSS

```
[id^="info"] { 

          display: none;
    }
```

JS

```
document.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
      var id = e.target.getAttribute('data-info-id');
      var checked = e.target.checked;
      if (id) {
        var div = document.getElementById(id);
        if (div)
          div.style.display = checked ? 'block' : 'none';
      }

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I first added two containing divs around the checkbox and the radio buttons:

```
<div id="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" id="item1" data-info-id="info1" />
    <label for="item1">Item 1 Checkbox</label>
</div>
<br/>
<div id="info1">Content checkbox group</div>
</p>
<div id="radios">
    <input type="radio" id="jb1" name="jb" />
    <label for="jb1">Item2 Radio</label>
    <br/>
    <input type="radio" id="jb2" name="jb" />
    <label for="jb2">Item3 Radio</label>
    <br/>
    <input type="radio" id="jb3" name="jb" data-info-id="info2" />
    <label for="jb3">Item4 Radio</label>
    <br/>
</div>
<div id="info2">Content radio group</div>
```

I then added a for loop to loop through the children of the parent of the item clicked. Because it was only triggering the change event for the clicked item.

```
document.addEventListener('change', function (e) {

    var children = e.target.parentNode.children;


    for(var i = 0; i < children.length ; i ++)
    {

        var id = children[i].getAttribute('data-info-id');
        var checked = children[i].checked;

        if (id) {
            var div = document.getElementById(id);
            if (div) div.style.display = checked ? 'block' : 'none';
        }

    }

});
```

This works for me. It's a little down and dirty but it works just fine.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not working if you want two of the 3 radio buttons to show the div and the first one to hide the div can you fix this?

Answer (score 0):

For the radio buttons. This can be done in 2 ways :
Here's the jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/zvzL8u1n/

---

**Method1**
 Have 2 radio buttons Show and Hide.

```
$("input[name=jbM1]").change(function(){
    $("#" + $(this).data("info-id")).toggle();
});
```

`jbM1` is the name for both the radio buttons.

So basically `data-info-id` is given in both the radio buttons and on their change the div is toggled.

---

**Method2**
 Have only one radio button and make it work like checkbox

```
$("#jb3").click(function(){
    var prev = $(this).data('prev');
    if(prev == true){
        $(this).prop('checked', false);
    }
    $(this).data('prev', $(this).prop('checked'));
    $("#" + $(this).data("info-id")).toggle();
});
```

`jb3` is id of the radio button and `data-prev` is used for storing prev value.